# Sqite Database data replication and exportation to another database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have this scenario, and here are the client's modifications so I think it's better to discuss the requirements with you first guys.
I have two sqlite databases that being instantiated upon the first load of the application, and the first Sqlite database (Say DB-1)is populated from a read and parsed text file in the assets folder (so DB-2 is empty).

The user is able to populate DB-2 by placing a text file in a folder in the phone's sd card, and then opening the application and clicking the import new database button.

So we always DB-1 populated, and DB-2 gets populated if the user places the text file on the phone's memory and clicks the import button.

The new requirements are:
After populating DB-2, the user wants to place another text file on the phone and press import, after he presses import he wants the DB-1 data to be deleted, data of DB-2 to be transferred to DB-1 and DB-2 to be populated by the new data from the text file.

What's the best approach to do so?
N.B DB-1 and DB-2 are of exact same structure

Comment: In short, you probably want to drop DB-1, rename DB-2, and create new DB-2. But you should test with a skeptical eye; I think it would be pretty easy for a user to end up with *two* empty databases.

Comment: can you elaborate more since DB-1 and DB-2 are of same structure but different classes, renaming the .db file wont affect anything?